# Single noun meaning completed task

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

Assuming that a task is a piece of work to be completed, is there a single word or noun that would be the antonym of a task, meaning a piece of work that has been completed?

So far my best bet is *accomplishment* or *achievement*, but I feel they imply the task was difficult and that completing it was an exploit.

An example sentence could be "Here is a list of your *accomplishments* this past week."

Comment: completed assignments

Comment: tasks are accomplished whether trivial or monumental.

Comment: 'Accomplishment' and 'achievement' were given _stipulative definitions_  in linguistics by Vendler to distinguish telic predicates that are durative (eat a pie) and punctive (pop a balloon) respectively; obviously, the _special, noteworthy_ caveat need not be present here. However, that caveat _does_, as you say, _normally_ inform the meaning of these two words, despite Jim's insistence on a different definition. @Lambie's suggestion is unmarked and hard to better.

Comment: We have been known to call them *to-do's* and *to-done's*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - I’ve also heard ta-da list.  Which I thought was clever.